# Pubnub javascript video chat camera and mic mute mechanism?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I have used PubNub video chat javascript api and it is doing well.Now I want to manage resources as follows:

1. I want to turn off & on camera  during chat.
2. I want to turn off & on mic during chat.

And in WebRTC at following [**url**](https://appr.tc/r/demo) we can see how they are making  camera and mic 
mute.

For it I could find only one method in webrtc-v2.js that is :

```
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    // Stop Camera/Mic
    // -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    function stopcamera() {
        if (!mystream) return;
        for (let track of mystream.getTracks()) track.stop();
    }
```

and If I use it **how can I precisely get track for mic And  camera.**
And after that **how can initiate them again**.

Comment: Sir! I do not want to camera off. I was saying in context of chat  to pause camera stream to transfer to remote user and same for mic. If we can stop the video and audio track in webrtc-v2.js and start it again then there might be a way to pause stream to transfer  and resume transfer.

Comment: Your question specifically asks: "I want to turn off & on camera during chat and I want to turn off & on mic during chat." Soooo, not sure why you are saying "I do not want to camera off". What do you mean by "transfer resume". That sounds like stop, send somewhere else, restart. Still don't think it is PubNub issue because PubNub doesn't stream the rich media unless there is some error with the publish/subscribe calls that you are making. Please provide more details about your issue: errors, more code, logs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Video Camera and Mic mute mechanism?

The SDK does not start Pause/Resume on streams.  You need to re-connect with a new session. Additionally the SDK does not have a mute method.

You can mute the local stream feed by setting the output render volume to 0.

```
let vid;
session.connected(function(session){
    vid = session.video;

    // Mute Audio
    vid.volume = 0.0;

    // Unmute Audio
    vid.volume = 1.0;
});
```

The SDK does not provide other methods for mute/unmute.